# Load modules dynamically according to the user permission from server to native/hybrid mobile app

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova-plugins, ionic4

*Diagram 1:*

[image]

I have a requirement to develop an Ionic 4 mobile app as shown above diagram. i.e. We just upload a Shell app or having very basic features on it like so.

[image]

Step 1: Send an activation code

Step 2: Then user login according to the response from it

Step 3: Dynamically load the relevant module to the app according to diagram 1.

Can I develop such an app? According to my knowledge where I think we cannot do it since we need to have everything upfront before build/wrapped using Cordova. Any clue here?

***Note:*** Dynamic App module download is the key here. We don't want to modify the shell when customer C comes onboard in the future for example.

Comment: So isn’t this exact use case for Ionic deploy service? its a pro service surely but clarification why that is not working for you would be helpful. https://ionicframework.com/pro/deploy

Comment: to add Ionic deploy only deals with web content modules and of course can not deal with native plugins. This is also due to App Store requirements for app updates and modules. Only select use cases are supported.

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I know about that service. But how can you compare that service with my requirement here? That service listens to the changes within the Ionic app itself. But here Ionic app doesn't know or implement anything related to those modules. Those modules must come from the server as a result of API call.  I assume we need `Ivy` kind of support here. But unfortunately, that will happen with `Angular 9` and next year. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9343#issuecomment-439345350

Comment: so maybe i am confused here but i thought you need to show custom web content and app logic (like components etc) but you are saying entire app module? I would check carefully Apple’s policy re such app updates that avoid app store flow. Even if you find such a solution it might conflict with developer terms

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes, you're right. I need to replace the whole module dynamically according to the API call of the user. If you can share a link about apple's restriction here that would be the answer to my question. I can tell about it to my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you need to convince client to leverage Ionic Pro's deploy service (that only deals with web content of the app package) or find other solution to the problem.

The proposed mechanics is risky considering this clause of Apple's developer guideline:

> 2.5.2 Apps should be self-contained in their bundles, and may not read or write data outside the designated container area, nor may they
>   download, install, or execute code which introduces or changes
>   features or functionality of the app, including other apps.
>   Educational apps designed to teach, develop, or allow students to test
>   executable code may, in limited circumstances, download code provided
>   that such code is not used for other purposes. Such apps must make the
>   source code provided by the Application completely viewable and
>   editable by the user.

From here: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#extensions